# angular - typescript error Type AnimatesDirective

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Hello im newbie using the ionic framework and sometimes i get errors when i try to compile like this and i dont understand it at all, i would thanks if you help me !

```
[13:33:41]  ngc started ...
[13:33:46]  typescript error
            Type AnimatesDirective in
            C:/Users/sportak/ionic/fitnessV2/fitness/node_modules/css-animator/angular/animates.directive.d.ts is part
            of the declarations of 2 modules: AnimatorModule in
            C:/Users/sportak/ionic/fitnessV2/fitness/node_modules/css-animator/angular/animator.module.d.ts and
            AppModule in C:/Users/sportak/ionic/fitnessV2/fitness/src/app/app.module.ts! Please consider moving
            AnimatesDirective in
            C:/Users/sportak/ionic/fitnessV2/fitness/node_modules/css-animator/angular/animates.directive.d.ts to a
            higher module that imports AnimatorModule in
            C:/Users/sportak/ionic/fitnessV2/fitness/node_modules/css-animator/angular/animator.module.d.ts and
            AppModule in C:/Users/sportak/ionic/fitnessV2/fitness/src/app/app.module.ts. You can also create a new
            NgModule that exports and includes AnimatesDirective in
            C:/Users/sportak/ionic/fitnessV2/fitness/node_modules/css-animator/angular/animates.directive.d.ts then
            import that NgModule in AnimatorModule in
            C:/Users/sportak/ionic/fitnessV2/fitness/node_modules/css-animator/angular/animator.module.d.ts and
            AppModule in C:/Users/sportak/ionic/fitnessV2/fitness/src/app/app.module.ts.

Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
    at C:\Users\sportak\ionic\fitnessV2\fitness\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:237:55
    at step (C:\Users\sportak\ionic\fitnessV2\fitness\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\sportak\ionic\fitnessV2\fitness\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:13:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\sportak\ionic\fitnessV2\fitness\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
[13:33:46]  copy finished in 4.61 s
```